# How do I generate PDF in Laravel Livewire with `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I have this little application I created with `Laravel Jetstream`, so obviously I created my pages with `Livewire and tailwindcss`. I implemented `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` to convert my pages into PDF, when I click the `Generate Button`, nothing happens, and after sometime it timeouts and displays `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`. What could be the problem?

// Livewire component

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Livewire\Component;

class DownloadButton extends Component
{
    public function generatePdf(): Response
    {
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('livewire.report-card-generator')->setPaper('A4');
        return $pdf->stream('report.pdf');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.download-button');
    }
}
```

//Blade file (This should generate into a PDF)

```
<div class="text-center border border-black p-4 mb-10 break-after-page">
        <h1 class="text-4xl font-bold">
            MOTHER'S GLORY EDUCATION CENTRE
        </h1>
        <p class="my-8">c/o P.O.BOX 1689. ACCRA-NORTH</p>
        <p class="my-10">
            Mob: +233(0) 267-340-745, 275-857-788, Email: mummy.glory13@yahoo.com
        </p>
        <img class="mt-40 mx-auto" src="{{asset('images/mgec-logo.jpeg')}}" alt="school-logo" width=200 height=200
        />
        <h1 class="text-2xl font-medium my-10">TERMINAL REPORT SHEET</h1>
        <h1 class="text-2xl font-medium my-20 bg-gray-300 p-4 mx-8">
            PRE-SCHOOL DEPARTMENT
        </h1>
        <input
            class="bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 focus:bg-white uppercase"
            type="text"
            placeholder="John Doe"
        />
    </div>
```

// Generate Button

```
<button class="text-white bg-blue-700" wire:click="generatePdf" wire:loading.attr="disabled"
        >
            <span wire:loading.remove>Generate PDF</span>
            <div wire:loading>
                Downloading Report...
            </div>
        </button>
```

Comment: try the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70296145/laravel-8-download-pdf-with-livewire

Comment: Ok I have views the link, but seems it's an Invoice library so all the methods are kind of method for generating sales invoice, I'm not sure how I can implement it in mine since mine is a School Report card generation.

Comment: I posted an answer, just doing according to the answer of the above question

Comment: Alright sir, after a long battle, seems it's working fine now, however my `tailwindcss` styling is not working in the PDF, is there anyway around it, or I should change everything to normal `CSS`?

Comment: there are some styles dompdf doesn't support

Comment: Alright no problem, I'm changing everything to inline css. But thank you very much for your help Sir. I appreciate. Your code is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: Sir one more thing, seems `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` is not rending my images, how do I configure it to export images into the PDF as well?

Comment: You can convert your image to base64 and then inject it to img src

Comment: Or you can set isRemoteEnabled option to true

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
return response()->streamDownload(function () use($pdf) {
    echo  $pdf->stream();
}, 'report.pdf');
```

Comment: if using Barryvdh\Snappy\PdfWrapper;

use $pdf->download() instead. stream() is depreciated.